# NDSolve and Contour Plot, 2D, Steady State, Internal Energy Generation

Tags: differential-equations

I am trying to create a contour plot of conducting block in two dimensions, with internal energy generation and an adiabatic wall. There are Dirichlet conditions on three sides, and a Neumann condition on one. I am relatively new to *Mathematica*, but tried to follow the examples in the `NDSolve` documentation to no avail.

Here is my code:

```
Tset = 200;
qdot = 1000000/.8;
sol =NDSolve[{D[T[x,y],x,x] + D[T[x,y],y,y] + qdot == 0, T[x,0] == Tset, T[0,y] == Tset, T[5,y] == Tset, D[T[x,10],y]== 0},T, {x,0,5}, {y,0,10}]
```

> During evaluation of In[10]:= NDSolve::deqn: Equation or list of equations expected instead of True in the first argument {1.25*10^6+(T^(0,2))[x,y]+(T^(2,0))[x,y]==0,T[x,0]==200,T[0,y]==200,T[5,y]==200,True}.
>
> ```
> NDSolve[{1.25*10^6+(T^(0,2))[x,y]+(T^(2,0))[x,y]==0,T[x,0]==200,T[0,y]==200,T[5,y]==200,True},T,{x,0,5},{y,0,10}]
> ```

```
ContourPlot[sol[x,y], {x,0,10}, {y,0,10}]
```

> During evaluation of In[13]:= NDSolve::dsvar: 0.0007142857142857143 cannot be used as a variable.
>
> During evaluation of In[13]:= NDSolve::dsvar: 0.0007142857142857143 cannot be used as a variable.
>
> During evaluation of In[13]:= NDSolve::dsvar: 0.715 cannot be used as a variable.
>
> During evaluation of In[13]:= General::stop: Further output of NDSolve::dsvar will be suppressed during this calculation.

How can I make this work?

Edit:

There were two questions within my question, how to setup the boundary conditions for my PDE, and how to get them into a contour plot. These have both been sufficiently solved! Thank you all!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As correctly pointed out in the answer by @eyorble, the issue is with the syntax of the Neumann condition. So you can `NeumannValue[0, y == 10]`. For details on `NeumannValue` check the [documentation](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/NeumannValue.html).

```
Tset = 200;
qdot = 1000000/0.8;

sol = NDSolve[{D[T[x, y], x, x] + D[T[x, y], y, y] + qdot == 
    NeumannValue[0, y == 10], T[x, 0] == Tset, T[0, y] == Tset, 
   T[5, y] == Tset}, T, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 10}]


ContourPlot[T[x, y] /. sol, {x, 0, 5}, {y, 0, 10}, AxesLabel -> {X, Y}, PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Yes! I can see that not much changed from what I wrote. I tried using NeumannValue as an argument, but it was "over-defined". Is there a way Mathematica treats NeumannValue that requires that syntax? Thank you so much for the assistance.

Answer (score 3):

Focus on the term `D[T[x,10],y] == 0`. The derivative of an expression for a variable not contained in that expression is always 0. *Mathematica* does not know that you mean to derive for the second variable when you say `y` there.

Instead, replace that term with `Derivative[0,1][T][x,10] == 0`, which refers to taking the derivative based on argument position (the 0th derivative with respect to the first argument and the 1st derivative with respect to the second argument) instead of based on which variables are present.

Furthermore, note that the solution is returned as a replacement list containing the function(s) solved for. `sol` is not itself a function.

Thus, the contour plot needs to be generated by substituting in the function `T` from the solution in `sol`.

```
ContourPlot[T[x, y] /. sol, {x, 0, 10}, {y, 0, 10}]
```

Finally, it is generally advised that you do not use capital letters to start user-defined variables or terms in *Mathematica*, as they may conflict with internal definitions.

Comment: Ah I see! Now that I am taking the derivative correctly using Derivative[], I am getting a slew of other errors. I also tried NeumannValue, with slightly more success, but still no dice.